# What is the best way to calculate numerical balances in the days of a calendar given deposits and withdrawals on various days?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, finance

This is not a syntactic / code type question where it's like can you give me the code for this, but more of a what's the best way to do this? (Linked List, etc.)

I want to create a calendar app where I can forecast finances into the future by adding stuff to the calendar like, on these dates X amount of income gets added, and on these dates Y gets removed because bills, whatever whatever..

I am trying to figure out the best way to have things calculated for ex. if you look up April, or May for 2023, and it shows only one month, or you view 2 months etc.

It seems like calculations would have to do done in realtime ? but that seems like it might be very expensive.

Recent idea I just had is have a beginning balance and ending balance for each timeframe. So like for each day, month etc. would have beginning/ending balance and then the starting balance would be linked to the ending balance of the previous month.

I've searched far and wide and I cannot find anything that does what I want so I need to create it myself but this involves problems I have never had to deal with or solve and I just want to get other opinions on what the best way to do this might be before I just jump into it.

It's basically going to be in Javascript in React most likely. Mobile version will probably be Swift since I'm keen on learning it and getting into mobile dev. The backend can be whatever I don't really care but I'm open to thoughts on what it should be.

Answer (score 1):

#### The most obvious approach is a spreadsheet

They are designed for exactly this type of question, and will take away the need for programming.

#### If you want to write it in Javascript, keep a list of dates and transactions

Then you can create a separate cumulative list of bank balances, by adding up those values.

To keep this efficient, you can calculate *one* cumulative list, and then look up the relevant value each time. A simple approach may be an object (dictionary) in which the keys are the dates at which any balance update took place, and the values are the end-of-day balances.

To know the balance at the end of any chosen date, look in the keys of the object and pick the last date that is not greater than that chosen date. The value at that key is the balance.

```js
const transactions = [{
    date: "2023-02-01",
    delta: +10
  },
  {
    date: "2023-02-02",
    delta: +100
  },
  {
    date: "2023-02-02",
    delta: -60
  },
  {
    date: "2023-02-15",
    delta: +200
  },
  {
    date: "2023-02-15",
    delta: -160
  },

]

let balance = 0 // Initial bank balance, before any of the transactions


// Calculation

const sortedTransactions = transactions.sort((t1, t2) => t1.date.localeCompare(t2.date))

const balanceUpdates = {}
sortedTransactions.forEach(transaction => {
  balance += transaction.delta;
  balanceUpdates[transaction.date] = balance
})


console.log(balanceUpdates)
```